# How do I model this curvy spiral staircase?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, screw-modifier

Can't figure out how to model this curvy spiral staircase. I initially tried freehanding it, but to no avail. I tried to figure out something with curves or the screw modifier, but it didn't work.

It seems like there should be an elegant way to do this, but I can't figure it out.

[image: Curvy thing]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well I think this is just supposed to be a spiral staircase, a fairly simple helix.

One way to model it would be to make a square "U" shape with three edges (e.g. delete one edge of a plane).  Rotate it so it's as shown in the image below (make sure to apply your rotation) and you'll want to offset the origin, in *Edit Mode*, just select the vertices and move <kbd>G</kbd> them to one side, which will leave the origin in place.

Then just add a *Screw* modifier as shown. I have set the Angle to negative to get the helix to twist the direction I want.

[image: spiral staircase]

**Edit:** as per @Duarte Farrajota Ramos, an *Edge Split* modifier would be a good addition to distinguish between the sharp angles and the smoother surfaces.

[image: spiral staircase with edge split modifier]

Comment: Might be worth mentioning adding an edgesplit modifier to the bottom of your staircase stack to get better smoothing, or turning auto smooth on.

Comment: Another thing to note is that the outer wall extends much higher than the inner wall.